# Identify instances where data NOT entered for t > n days [python]

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, missing-data, flags

I'm looking for a method to identify instances where data has not been entered for a number of days. In my case I would like to flag when no data has been entered for > 5 days.

An example of the type of dataset can be found in this table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0s86.png

I've tried a number of methods, including replacing the missing data with date variables and subtracting the difference but haven't been able to come up with anything useful.

Latest code:

```
df = 'table.csv'

df['Rolling'] = np.roll(df['Count'],1)

df['Count'] = df['Count'].fillna('MISSING')
df.loc[ df['Count'] == 'MISSING', 'Count'] = df['Date']
diff = df['Count'].astype('int32') - df['Rolling'].astype('int32')
df['Difference'] = diff

df.head()
```

What I have bee trying (and failing) to attempt next was to create a new column that only includes the date when data is entered and use that to try and calculate the differences.

As always, any help greatly appreciated.

-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before suggesting an answer I would like to point you to this very helpful article: [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples), so people who want to answer your question can just use your dataframe directly

In the absence of that here is a sample dataframe I used:

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
start_date = datetime(2015,11,4)
dates = [start_date + timedelta(days =x) for x in range(20)]
count = [np.nan]*len(dates)
count[9] = 10
count[11] = 20
count[17] = 30
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':dates, 'Obs':count})
df
```

that looks like this

```
    Date        Obs
0   2015-11-04  NaN
1   2015-11-05  NaN
2   2015-11-06  NaN
3   2015-11-07  NaN
4   2015-11-08  NaN
5   2015-11-09  NaN
6   2015-11-10  NaN
7   2015-11-11  NaN
8   2015-11-12  NaN
9   2015-11-13  10.0
10  2015-11-14  NaN
11  2015-11-15  20.0
12  2015-11-16  NaN
13  2015-11-17  NaN
14  2015-11-18  NaN
15  2015-11-19  NaN
16  2015-11-20  NaN
17  2015-11-21  30.0
18  2015-11-22  NaN
19  2015-11-23  NaN
```

Note I assume you have NaNs for dates when there is data

So we can do the following -- we can groupby all the blocks between non-NaN observatiobs, which is achieved via `(~df['Count'].isna()).cumsum())` calculation below -- this Series increments at indices where non-NaN 'Count' is detected. Once we groupby on that we can get some statistics on the groups. So

```
df.groupby((~df['Obs'].isna()).cumsum()).agg({'Date':['first','last', 'count']})
```

produces

```
    Date
    first       last        count
Obs
0   2015-11-04  2015-11-12  9
1   2015-11-13  2015-11-14  2
2   2015-11-15  2015-11-20  6
3   2015-11-21  2015-11-23  3
```

The way to read this is the first block of NaNs went from 2015-11-04 to 2015-11-12 and had 9 entries, the second from 2015-11-13 to 2015-11-14 and had 2, etc (inner blocks will include one of the actual observations so # of NaNs is 'count'-1). So you can see which block was longer than 5 (or whatever), and you know when it started and finished

Comment: Incredible! You sir are a STAR. This is exactly what I am trying to do. I am still but a padawan in the Python galaxy so your wisdom is greatly appreciated. I'll be sure to adhere to the ways of great pandas in future.

Comment: One more question if you're still around @pitebarg. Why the '~' in front of df in the groupby statement?

Comment: '~' means 'not' in Boolean indexing in Pandas, so (~df['Obs'].isna()) is a list of True/False with True when the corresponding element in df['Obs'] is NOT a NaN

Comment: Hah... thanks! That is very useful. Not sure I'd have come across it any time soon in my meandering self taught python journey...

Comment: One last thing @piterbarg - is there any way to use that groupby statement and still include the ID column? like columns =  [id, first, last, count]

Comment: @johnconora sure, for example you can include it in the groupby criteria: `df.groupby([df['ID'],(~df['Obs'].isna()).cumsum()]).agg({'Date':['first','last', 'count']})`

Comment: You're a god amongst men piterbarg... don't let anyone tell you different!